# How to run multiple files in one container image and use the output as input in another container in Argo workflow?

Tags: kubernetes, argo-workflows

I am trying to run 2 python files in one container , save the output as parameters:

```
- name: training
    serviceAccountName: argo-service
    outputs:
      parameters:
        - name: output-param-1
          valueFrom:
            path: ./tmp/output.txt
        - name: output-param-2
          valueFrom:
            path: ./tmp/output2.txt
    container:
      image: (image name)
      command: [python]
      args: ["/data/argo/model_build.py","/data/argo/model_build_2.py"]
```

Use that output as input in another container :

```
- name: evaluate
    serviceAccountName: argo-service
    inputs:
        parameters:
          - name: value-1
          - name: value-2
    container:
      image: (image name)
      command: ["python", "/data/argo/evaluate.py"]
      args: 
          - '{{inputs.parameters.value-1}}'
          - '{{inputs.parameters.value-2}}'
```

and have defined the chain as :

```
 - name: dag-chain
    dag:
      tasks:
      - name: src
        template: clone-repo
      - name: prep
        template: data-prep
        dependencies: [src]
      - name: train
        template: training
        dependencies: [prep]
      - name: eval
        template: evaluate
        dependencies: [train]
        args:
          parameters:
            - name: value-1
              value: '{{dag-chain.tasks.train.outputs.parameters.output-param-1}}'
            - name: value-2
              value: '{{dag-chain.tasks.train.outputs.parameters.output-param-2}}'
```

But with these steps I'm getting the error :

" Internal Server Error: templates.dag-chain.tasks.eval templates.evaluate inputs.parameters.value-1 was not supplied: "

Please help me identify the mistakes I'm making.

I have tried the steps mentioned above but it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have Argo accessible just now to test, but a couple of things to try:

- `args` in DAG tasks should be `arguments` (see field reference for a DAG task [here](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-workflows/fields/#dagtask)).
- Try removing `dag-chain` from the parameters (see example [here](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-workflows/workflow-inputs/#using-previous-step-outputs-as-inputs)).

```yaml
 - name: dag-chain
    dag:
      tasks:
      - name: src
        template: clone-repo
      - name: prep
        template: data-prep
        dependencies: [src]
      - name: train
        template: training
        dependencies: [prep]
      - name: eval
        template: evaluate
        dependencies: [train]
        arguments:
          parameters:
            - name: value-1
              value: '{{tasks.train.outputs.parameters.output-param-1}}'
            - name: value-2
              value: '{{tasks.train.outputs.parameters.output-param-2}}'
```

If that doesn't work I'll try some more steps with Argo.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. Your suggestions helped and I also changed the paths. Thank you very much.

Comment: The issue now is that it is not running the 2nd python file in the training container.

Comment: A docker image won't run two Python files in a row by simply providing two python file paths to the Python executable. You need to look at something like this instead: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-run-multiple-python-file-in-a-folder-one-after-another/